# Method cannot be declared public because its parameter uses an internal type

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swift4

I have an auto-generated accessors for an Entity:

```
//auto-generated code:
extension Entity1{
  @objc(addEntity1toEntity2Object:)
  @NSManaged public func addEntity1toEntity2Object(_ value: Entity2)
  ...
}
```

and I get a build Error:

> Method cannot be declared public because its parameter uses an internal type

Answer (score 2):

Entity2 should be declared ***public*** explicitly:

```
public class Entity2{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I found solution for you :
Change the default Codegen option for the entity from "Class Definition" to "Manual/None". You may have to clean your project before you build it again. The Codegen option can be found in the Data Model inspector when you select an entity. then create NSManagedObject subclass generator from Editor->Create NSManagedObject subclass.

Clean Project and build it.

refer to this answer options 2:
https://forums.raywenderlich.com/t/chapter-2-error-bowtie-is-ambiguous-for-type-lookup-in-this-context/22386/2

Answer (score 0):

change it to private?

```
@NSManaged private func addEntity1toEntity2Object(_ value: Entity2)
```

Comment: you can't do that because it's auto-generated code from core-data

Comment: @AviramNet it can be create by click relationships, then click Editor on top bar -> Create NSManagedObject Subclass. then change it to private, and save it.

Answer (score -1):

you are using extension so why you use public in :

```
@NSManaged public func addEntity1toEntity2Object(_ value: Entity2)
```